# How do I make the background image responsive during window resize

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a section layout where I just want only half of my image to be shown in the bottom, right-hand corner of the section. I can adjust the position and size of the background, but when I start resizing the window, the image either disappears, or moves from where I actually wanted it to be. I basically just want the layout to be responsive. I can't use px values for the background position, because when I adjust the window even slightly, the background photo looks terribly misplaced.

My code (you need to fullscreen the code snippet to see what I kind of want it to look like):

```css
html, body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
}

.one {
  background: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/45889/camera-photo-camera-sony-alpha-7-sony-45889.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940") no-repeat 130% 110%/300px;
    height: 100vh;
}

.two {
  background: #f3f3f3
}
```

```html
<section class="one">
  <header>First Section</header>
</section>
<section class="two">
  <header>Second Section</header>
</section>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Or if this isn't possible. I also tried using `Transform`, which didn't work out well either.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/webdevpchoi/pen/LJEzJM)

Comment: in your codepen you have an img tag and in the question you have set the image as a background ...what do you actually want?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `position: fixed;` and play with `top`: and `left:` values.

Edit: With responsive positions in any elelment use `%` in size ;)

Eg.

```
.one {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/45889/camera-photo-camera-sony-alpha-7-sony-45889.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940") no-repeat 130% 110%/300px;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Hope this can help you ;)